# mysqlimport reports Error: 29, File '/tmp/newTable.txt' not found (Errcode: 13), when using table: newTable

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

For a while not I have been trying to import a tab separated text file into my mysql database. I keep getting this error.

A few forums advised that I should change the mode of the file and folder to 777. Which I did, but still the same error.

```
Error: 29, File '/tmp/vehicleMake.txt' not found (Errcode: 13), when using table: vehicleMake
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry for trouble, I used --local option and it worked.. Magic!!!

Comment: It doesn't work anymore with recent versions of MySQL

Answer (score 1):

The LOCAL option is no longer supported in most versions of MYSQL. In Ubuntu 14.04 and MYSQL 5.5 I moved the file to the /tmp directory and changed ownership of the file to mysql using the following in the shell:

```
sudo chown mysql.mysql <filename>
```